# Takes time to switch between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have different activities with lots of `drawables`. all of them are set as src or background in `layout` itself to the different `ImageViews`.

Now suppose Activity A,B has 50 such images and so each.
When i start B activity it takes almost 2~3 seconds to load the `activity`.
Can't this be reduced to normal.

Answer (score 0):

One would argue this **is** normal. That's a lot of images to load/unload from memory at once.

Though it also depends on the device, if this is a Android Virtual Machine, for instance, you should definitely expect better results on an actual device; or if you just put the app on a device with more power it'll load faster.